# How to change RStudio display

Tags: r, rstudio

After importing the exact same dataset, the display my friend got is the actual meanings behind the numbers, but what I got are numbers assigned to those meanings.
For example, for the 'sex' variable, 1-female and 2-male. What I got in the column display is "1""2""1""2", but my friend got "female""male""female""male".

And I wonder how can I change my display into hers. Many thanks in advance!

[image: My friend's display]

[image: My display]

Comment: I'll add that it might be more informative to [edit] your question and post the output of `dput(head(x))` into a [code block](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) instead of `str`. The R console can hide a lot of (important) properties of objects, and `dput` mitigates that risk.

Answer (score 0):

Please post the exact code both you and your friend used to import the dataset. I suspect that it has something to do with the data being (not) imported as factors. Maybe through `stringsAsFactors=TRUE` for you and not for your friend.

Also, please run the `str(ca_indresp_w)` command to output the types of the columns and post the output as a comment. I will then edit the answer in accordance to the new info.

Answer (score 0):

as @marvinschmitt mentioned - check the meaning of the `stringsAsFactors` parameter to `data.frame` and/or `?read.table` on which `?read.csv` is based
In case you have not minggled with that parameter on import (via some `read.` function) I am guessing that your friend is running version R-4 and you are maybe running version R-3, where one of the main changes to this R majopr version upgrade was changing the `stringsAsFactors` options global default from `TRUE` (before R-4) to `FALSE` (since R-4).